# doctest running in sphinx doc

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, doctest

I am trying to run doctest written in my rst doc. But I can't get how to run it. I've written the following:

```
.. doctest::

    >>> 43 + 1
    45
```

And then I do:

```
$ make html
```

but doc is build successfully.

I am also interested if the one can just run test without building html doc?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the [doctest docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html) for configuration and usage.

Comment: Did you try "make doctest"?

Comment: >Did you try "make doctest"?

It runs all doctest (even from the code). Maybe it is possible to run only from some rst?

Comment: How about using `python -m doctest -v example.rst`? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#simple-usage-checking-examples-in-a-text-file

Comment: It doesn't run code in `.. testcode::` `.. testoutput::` directive and you should specify files one by one, it doesn't accept folder

Comment: Please update the question and show us what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: Hello @mzjn. Actually I got the right the command I want, it was actually more ease, than I thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

So, that was actually not that hard. I should just run the following command:

```
$ pytest 'path to static rst files' --doctest-glob=*.rst --doctest-module
```